# How to avoid repeating suits in if statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, repeat

I have a code that looks:

```
if condition1:
  do1
  if condition2:
    do2
  else:
    do3
else:
  do3
```

where `do2` and `do3` operate on the same variables. Is there a way to reduce this code somehow, to avoid having `do3` twice?

Thanks!

Comment: remove the else in the middle

Comment: I should have mentioned that either `do2` or `do3` must be executed. that option would result in cases where none are done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think of something like this to avoid do3 twice

```
if condition1:
    do1
elif condition2:
    do2
else:
    do3
```

Comment: You are welcome, we are more than glad to be of assistance @DávidPapp!